# Within the iOS app, a push notification is received several times

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

My iOS app receives a push notification. Then the app is closed and runs in the background. After reopening the app, the push notification is received again. Only when the app is completely closed does the push notification no longer occur. Why? How can you prevent this?

Comment: this is not default behaviour. What is your push related code?

Comment: 1. Get Device token with Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications  2. Subscribe to push channel with Ti.App.Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken  3. Callback event to receive the push when the app is open.  The push message always appears in the callback, as long as the app is not closed completely. There are various push messages in the app that are received when the app is open. Therefore, I can not do without the callback.